# Looking for adequate Data Structure (Collection, Map, LocalDateTime)

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I want a data structure that contain the following:

- Two Objects that represent a timeslot (e.g. LocalDateTime in Java 8)
- A boolean variable

The Timeslot needs to be connected to a boolean. The program needs to know if a timeslot is available. It will be used in a knapsack problem solving algorithm for work scheduling.

What I've got so far:

```
ArrayList<Map<List<LocalDateTime>, Boolean>>
```

But it looks pretty complicated and a Map might not be the best way to iterate through if I don't know the key. I tought about a ArrayList instead of a Map but I don't know how to initialize it with different Data Types.

Answer (score 1):

[`Table`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) from Google Guava sounds like a perfect fit for this.

```
Table<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime, Boolean> dateTable
                       = TreeBasedTable.create();
```

The reason for it is that it gives you access to row, column, and value (in parameter order), and will allow you to do relatively straightforward lookups.

An example:  If you want to find all of the values for a given `LocalDateTime` row, then you would do this:

```
LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.of(2014, Month.JULY, 26, 0, 0);
// prints a map of all of today's values
System.out.println(dateTable.row(today));
```

Comment: I tried it and thought about it. It might not be the right solution. There is just one combination of two LocalDateTime Objects. In a Table it would just be filled diagonal. Like <start monday 9am, end monday 5pm, true>, <start tuesday 9am, end monday 5pm, false>, etc.